# Finding element with slash in the ID using Playwright

Tags: python, playwright, webautomation, playwright-python

I have an element in my page with a slash (/) character in his id:

id=A/BC

When I try to find these element using Playwright it fails:

```
element_info = '#A/BC'
self.page.locator(self.element_info).click()
```

I got this error in the stack:

**E       playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Unexpected token "/" while parsing selector "#A/BC"
E       =========================== logs ===========================
E       waiting for selector "#A/BC" to be visible
E       ============================================================**

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select it by attribute:

```
self.page.locator('[id=\'#A/BC\']').click()
```